# Getting Current User Without Global Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, unit-testing

I have a service call `DataManager` that needs a reference to the current `IPrincipal` user.  However, I don't want to use a global reference like `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` or  `HttpContext.Current.User` because I want to be able to unit test it and specify any user for any given test. But I also don't want to construct a new `DataManager` for each thread in a multi-threaded environment (like WebApi or Web Services).

Is it bad practice or will it break anything if I inject (via constructor) an `IPrincipal` implementation that internally uses `HttpContext.Current.User` or `HttpContext.Current.User`?  Otherwise how should I handle this?

The solution I am thinking of looks like this:

```
public class DataManager {
        public DataManager(IPrincipal currentUser){
                this.currentUser = currentUser;
        }
        private IPrincipal currentUser;
        ...
        public void DoWork(){
                var currentUserName = currentUser.Identity.Name;
                // Do work here
        }
}
```

And then, when using this in ASP.NET, pass in an IPrincipal implementation that references the HTTP context's current user:

```
public class CurrentUser : IPrincipal {
    public IIdentity Identity {
        get {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        }
    }
    public bool IsInRole(string role) {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, I always end up creating a "IUserProvider" interface, and then I wrap the code needed for fetching the current user in an implementation matching the environment I run in (test, asp.net mvc, asp.net web api, etc.)

Comment: Interesting, do you do that to be more explicit that its not a single user?